# error: prototype for ' ' does not match any in class ' ';

Tags: c++

I recently started coding in c++ and was doing a project. Currently I'm using multiple files, one as a header, one for cpp code, and one as a main file. I've been stuck on a problem for a while now and I just cant figure out whats wrong. Whenever I compile the cpp file I get the error prototype for ‘GradeCalculator::GradeCalculator(const int*, const int&)’ does not match any in class ‘GradeCalculator’. I would really love to get some help and explanation on whats going wrong, here's my code:

//main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GradeCalculator.h"

#define NUM_ASSIGNMENTS 100

int main() {
    int points[NUM_ASSIGNMENTS];
    int newsize = 0;
    GradeCalculator gradecalculator(points, newsize);
    std::cout << "Grade Calculator\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "================\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "This program will calculate your grade average on your assignments.\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Your lowest grade will be dropped.\n" << std::endl;
    newsize = gradecalculator.addPoints(points);
    gradecalculator.printResults(points, newsize);
    return 0;
}
```

//header file:

```
#ifndef DEMO_GRADECALC_H
#define DEMO_GRADECALC_H
#include <iostream>

class GradeCalculator{
private:
    int points[100];
    int size;
public:
    GradeCalculator(int* points, int size);
    int addPoints(int*points);
    int dropLowest(int* points, int size);
    explicit GradeCalculator(const int* points, const int size);
    void printResults(int* points, int size);

    virtual ~GradeCalculator();

};

#endif
```

//cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GradeCalculator.h"

GradeCalculator::GradeCalculator(const int* points, const int &size){

}

int GradeCalculator::addPoints(int* points){
    int sizeofarray = 0;
    for( int j = 0; points[j] = '\0'; j++){
        std::cin >> points[j];
        sizeofarray ++;
    }
    return sizeofarray;
}

int GradeCalculator::dropLowest(int* points, int size) {
    int lowest = points[0];
    int lowestIndex = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        if( points[i] < lowest ) {
            lowest = points[i];
            lowestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    for( int i = lowestIndex; i < size-1; i++ ) {
        points[i] = points[i+1];
    }
    return size - 1;
}

void GradeCalculator::printResults(int* points, int size){
    dropLowest(points, size);
    int newtotal;
    for(int k = 0; points[k] = '\0'; k++){
        newtotal += points[k];
    }
    float avg = newtotal/size;
    std::cout << "Total Points: " << newtotal << "\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Average: " << avg << "\n" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: you are defining constructor with a reference: const int &size in cpp file, they don't match with header

Comment: @Asphodel, alright, I tried this and changed the code in the header into &size instead of just size when being referenced. This got rid of the original problem, but now im getting a problem saying that there are undefined references to 'GradeCalculator::GradeCalculator(int*, int&), 'GradeCalculator::~GradeCalculator()', and 'vtable for GradeCalculator'. Any idea on what this means and how to fix it?

Comment: @CarterScull You have a starting version compiling [here](https://godbolt.org/z/WTqe98GPx). I removed one of the two constructors, the one using `explicit`, and left the custom constructor and the destructor with an empty body within the class declaration. You need now to feed the data to your program and test it.